# Data in 'context' is not passed to HTML

Tags: python, django, request, render

The context within the first conditional statement is delivered well, but the context updated within the second conditional statement is not delivered in HTML.

For example, 'MODEL_LIST' in first context is delivered well, but 'mape_val' in second context is not. I want it to be delivered.

How Can I solve this problem ?

<views.py function CODE>

```
def csv_forecast(request):

    context = {}
    username = request.user
    
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES.get('csvfile'):
        uploaded_file = request.FILES.get('csvfile')

        p_data = pd.read_csv(uploaded_file)
        p_data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        columns_list = list(p_data.columns)
        columns_list = [column.lower() for column in columns_list]
        p_data.columns = columns_list

        os.makedirs('media/csv', exist_ok=True)
        p_data.to_csv(f'media/csv/{username}.csv', index=False)

        start_date = p_data.loc[0, 'date']
        len_date = int(len(p_data)*0.8)
        end_date = p_data.loc[len_date, 'date']
        datas = [] 
        
        for i in range(1, len(columns_list)):
            datas.append(columns_list[i])
        
        MODEL_LIST = ['ARIMA', 'EMA5', 'LSTM']
        
        context = {'datas' : datas, 'd' : p_data, 'columns_list' : columns_list, 'MODEL_LIST' : MODEL_LIST,
        'start_date' : start_date, 'end_date' : end_date}
        

    if request.POST.get('sendModel') and request.POST.get('sendPdata') and request.POST.get('sendRdata'):
    
        send_pdata = request.POST.get('sendPdata')
        send_rdata = request.POST.get('sendRdata')
        send_model = request.POST.get('sendModel')
        cleaned_pdata = re.split(r'[\[\],"]', send_pdata)
        cleaned_rdata = re.split(r'[\[\],"]', send_rdata)
        cleaned_model = re.split(r'[\[\],"]', send_model)
        selected_pdata = [i for i in cleaned_pdata if len(i) >= 1]
        selected_rdata = [i for i in cleaned_rdata if len(i) >= 1]
        selected_model = [i for i in cleaned_model if len(i) >= 1]

        csv_data = pd.read_csv(f'media/csv/{username}.csv')
        mape_val, y_pred, y_test, test_date = model_main(csv_data, selected_pdata,selected_rdata, selected_model)
        mape_val = float(mape_val)
        print(mape_val)
        
        fs = FileSystemStorage(location=f'media/csv/')
        fs.delete(f'{username}.csv')
        
        context.update({'mape_val':mape_val, 'y_pred':y_pred, 'y_test':y_test, 'test_date':test_date})

    return render(request, 'csv_forecast.html', context)
```

[HTML CODE PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaX5n.png)

[HTML PAGE PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOgzV.png)

[Debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeWPU.png)

[Debug Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcApA.png)

Comment: Can you show some debug to confirm the second condition is actually passing, like showing the output from printing `request.POST`? Is `print(mape_val)` being executed and/or outputting anything?

Comment: I add pictures. Please look debugging and debug console

Comment: The issue is the condition "if request.POST.get('sendModel') and request.POST.get('sendPdata') and request.POST.get('sendRdata')" are not true in your case such that the context is never got updated. check the value of each .get()

Comment: The second conditional statement is true. And context.update is going well. But render is problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.